# The best overload for List issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.DropDownList(expression: model => model.CategoryID, 
   new List<SelectListItem>(Model.CategorySelectListItem, dataValueField: "Value",
   dataTextField: "Text"),htmlAttributes:new {@class = "form-control"})
```

This is my code, what does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a new instance of [`SelectList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_) actually not a List of `SelectListItem`, change your code like this and it works fine:

```
@Html.DropDownList(expression: model => model.CategoryID,
      new SelectList(Model.CategorySelectListItem, dataValueField: "Value", 
      dataTextField: "Text"),htmlAttributes:new {@class = "form-control"})
```